# Mounting a dataset from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, mount

I am trying to mount the Wikipedia Pafe Traffic Statistics Dataset V3, and after following the steps that are indicated in the web side I fail in the last one. After typing the instruction:

```
mount /dev/sdf /mnt/wikidata
```

I got all the time the next error, and I don't know how to follow.

```
mount: /dev/xvdf is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S.: Just to add some info about the problem. After doing dmesg | tail, that is what I obtained:

```
[597690.810220] udevd[626]: starting version 173
[597691.355869] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x206d7, pf=0x1, revision=0x70a
[597691.357174] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[597691.389434] alg: No test for crc32 (crc32-pclmul)
[597693.100615] EXT4-fs (xvda1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[597693.965499] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[597701.672666] type=1305 audit(1396861711.653:2): audit_pid=1014 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
 res=1
[597923.451874] blkfront: xvdf: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: disabled; indirect descriptors: disabled;
[597923.686899]  xvdf: xvdf1
```

PS2:
Ok! I've solved the problem and now it is mounted. After checking with lsblk the available devices i saw:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvdf    202:80   0  170G  0 disk 
└─xvdf1 202:81   0  170G  0 part 
xvda1   202:1    0    8G  0 disk /
```

So mounting xvdf1 instead of xvdc was done!

Comment: I'm posting the answer here so it's apparent there's a solution.  In the future you CAN post your own answer after 24 hours or so.

Answer (score 16):

you cannot mount using `/dev/xvdf` but you can with the underlying `/dev/xvdf1`

- run `$lsblk` and find the volume you wanted to mount

`NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvdf    202:80   0  170G  0 disk 
└─xvdf1 202:81   0  170G  0 part`

- run the correct command `sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /mnt`

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was a little different.

I got the same error when running `sudo mount /dev/xvdf data`. It turned out I had forgotten to create a file system...

```
$ sudo file -s /dev/xvdf
/dev/xvdf: data
```

so I did that next.

```
$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdf
```

File system created.

```
$ sudo file -s /dev/xvdf
/dev/xvdf: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=9570ea53-2da5-41ae-a682-7c3044c20bd8 (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

Then, unlike the other answers, there was no `xvdf1` partition under `xvdf`...

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0  100G  0 disk
```

...but I was able to mount `xvdf` directly.

```
$ sudo mount /dev/xvdf /data
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a different mount-point? (i.e. /dev/sdg /mnt/wikidata) Also try your commands using sudo to ensure there aren't any permissions issues.

Comment: I've done with sudo, and the problem isn't there. About the mount-point the issue is that the wikipedia dataset is in /dev/sdf, so I need to do it with that one.